# Collect Data From User Tasks Not Firing Secondary Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a multi-step SPD approval workflow that creates several 'collect data from users' tasks and to date this process is working perfectly.

The request was made to create a custom email to notify the task's assigned to of the task. To accomplish this I created a new secondary workflow to send custom emails on the WorkFlow Tasks list in which the collect data tasks are created in.

My problem is that the workflow is not firing on the workflow created tasks, and is not listed as being available to start manually from a manually created collect data from user task. It is available from the Workflow Task content type. The collect data content types are correctly inheriting from WorkFlow Task.

Comment: Apparently it was set up correctly. I left it on and enabled and had a user report recieving an email this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was set up correctly. I left it on and enabled and had a user report recieving an email this morning.